# How could process.nextTick throw "RangeError: Invalid array length"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a stack trace for an error I started receiving in my Node.js application:

```
"RangeError: Invalid array length",
"    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:265:15)",
"    at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:96:5)",
"    at Socket._write (net.js:653:5)",
"    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:225:10)",
"    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:215:5)",
"    at Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:182:11)",
"    at Socket.write (net.js:615:40)",
```

(this is longjohn output)

Here is the offending line: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.31/lib/_stream_writable.js#L265

What could possibly cause this? Is it true that there's no way for my application source to have directly caused it because it's the call to `process.nextTick` that throws the error?

Comment: I have received errors with weird stack traces in the past that seemed to not come from my application, but, as far as i can remember, they always ended up being caused by my application code or from a module i was using. Tracing them can be difficult in large applications, but usually involves heavy use of logging.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by our usage of longjohn. Issue filed at https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn/issues/42. Fix submitted at https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn/pull/43